# Adding columns to tribble

Tags: r

I am trying to write a pipeline using `tribble` to create a column `date_new` of type `Date` by parsing the character column `date`. Additionally, I am using `separate()` to split year, month, and date components into separate columns first then plan to use `lubridate::make_date()` in the end.

My code:

```
tribble(
  ~date, ~height,
  "2020-06-22", "188 cm",
  "2020-06-23", "1.73 m",
  NA_character_, "192 cm",
  "6/27/2020", "175 cm",
  "6/28/2020", "165 cm",
  "6/29/2020", "191 cm",
  "2020-06-30", "1.85 m"
) %>%
  separate(date, into = c("c1", "c2", "c3")) %>%
  mutate(date_new = lubridate::make_date(year = c1, month = c2, day = c3))
```

However I am getting the output now as:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  c1    c2    c3    height date_new  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <date>    
1 2020  06    22    188 cm 2020-06-22
2 2020  06    23    1.73 m 2020-06-23
3 NA    NA    NA    192 cm NA        
4 6     27    2020  175 cm NA        
5 6     28    2020  165 cm NA        
6 6     29    2020  191 cm NA        
7 2020  06    30    1.85 m 2020-06-30
```

The 4,5,6 rows are converted to NA but I want it to be in `YYYY-MM-DD` respectively.

Comment: One challenge is it looks like the dates are in different formats (YYYY-MM-DD and MM/DD/YYYY).  Look into the `mutate()` function to add new columns and the `lubridate` package to parse dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(date = anydate(date))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  date       height
#  <date>     <chr> 
#1 2020-06-22 188 cm
#2 2020-06-23 1.73 m
#3 NA         192 cm
#4 2020-06-27 175 cm
#5 2020-06-28 165 cm
#6 2020-06-29 191 cm
#7 2020-06-30 1.85 m
```

---

If we want to split into three columns

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(date = anydate(date)) %>% 
   separate(date, into = c('c1', 'c2', 'c3'), remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(date2 = make_datetime(year = c1, month = c2, day = c3))
# A tibble: 7 x 6
#  date          c1    c2    c3 height date2              
#  <date>     <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <dttm>             
#1 2020-06-22  2020     6    22 188 cm 2020-06-22 00:00:00
#2 2020-06-23  2020     6    23 1.73 m 2020-06-23 00:00:00
#3 NA            NA    NA    NA 192 cm NA                 
#4 2020-06-27  2020     6    27 175 cm 2020-06-27 00:00:00
#5 2020-06-28  2020     6    28 165 cm 2020-06-28 00:00:00
#6 2020-06-29  2020     6    29 191 cm 2020-06-29 00:00:00
#7 2020-06-30  2020     6    30 1.85 m 2020-06-30 00:00:00
```

---

In the OP's updated code, the 'date' should be first converted to `Date` class, within `separate` specify `convert = TRUE` to convert the type before using `make_date`

```
 tribble(
  ~date, ~height,
  "2020-06-22", "188 cm",
  "2020-06-23", "1.73 m",
  NA_character_, "192 cm",
  "6/27/2020", "175 cm",
  "6/28/2020", "165 cm",
  "6/29/2020", "191 cm",
  "2020-06-30", "1.85 m"
) %>% 
   mutate(date = as.Date(parse_date_time(date, c('ymd', 'mdy')))) %>%
   separate(date, into = c("c1", "c2", "c3"), convert = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(date_new = lubridate::make_date(year = c1, month = c2, day = c3))
# A tibble: 7 x 5
#     c1    c2    c3 height date_new  
#  <int> <int> <int> <chr>  <date>    
#1  2020     6    22 188 cm 2020-06-22
#2  2020     6    23 1.73 m 2020-06-23
#3    NA    NA    NA 192 cm NA        
#4  2020     6    27 175 cm 2020-06-27
#5  2020     6    28 165 cm 2020-06-28
#6  2020     6    29 191 cm 2020-06-29
#7  2020     6    30 1.85 m 2020-06-30
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs, it would be helpful to how to proceed with the `separate()` logic of mine. I would like to primarily in that form.

Comment: @RanjiRaj if you add `%>% separate(date, into = c('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))` what is the issue with that

Comment: @RanjiRaj Based on your descrption in the question, you want to use `make_date`, I updated the post

Comment: May I know in your new column for `date2` the datatype is `dttm` and for me it is `date` why is that so?

Comment: @RanjiRaj It is just that the column type is `POSIXct`.  You can wrap with `as.Date` to have `Date` class.  We used `make_datetime`

Comment: Can you kindly look for the edited post after the changes that I made after your answer? I am probably missing a parsing but I want to go with `lubridate` implementation.

Comment: yes, this was the implementation I needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `parse_date_time` with a list of the different formats to test:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tribble(
  ~date, ~height,
  "2020-06-22", "188 cm",
  "2020-06-23", "1.73 m",
  NA_character_, "192 cm",
  "6/27/2020", "175 cm",
  "6/28/2020", "165 cm",
  "6/29/2020", "191 cm",
  "2020-06-30", "1.85 m"
) %>%
  mutate(date=as_date(parse_date_time(date,orders= c("ymd", "mdy"))))

#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   date       height
#>   <date>     <chr> 
#> 1 2020-06-22 188 cm
#> 2 2020-06-23 1.73 m
#> 3 NA         192 cm
#> 4 2020-06-27 175 cm
#> 5 2020-06-28 165 cm
#> 6 2020-06-29 191 cm
#> 7 2020-06-30 1.85 m
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know how to go about the `separate()` and then possibly add `mutate()`